# how to create selection with yes and no option in ruby

Tags: ruby

Create a Ruby program which calculates student fees
I need to ask student to answer question like   "Are you a state resident", "Want a parking decal?" and the code will executed based on the user input.

But I am having trouble with Yes/No selection part. whatever user input will only be select to No. which I do not know why is that happens. Thank you.

```
puts "Are you a state resident[0] or not[1]:"
resident = gets
resident = resident.to_i

case resident
    when 0
        enrollment_fee = 46.00
    when 1
        enrollment_fee = 335.00

end

puts "'enrollment_fee' + #{enrollment_fee}"

puts "Want a parking decal? [y/n]:"
parking = gets
parking = parking.to_s

puts parking
if parking == 'y'
    case semester
        when 0,2
            parking_decal = 85
        when 1,3
            parking_decal = 45
        end

else parking == 'n'
    parking_decal = 0.00
```

end

Answer (score 2):

`gets` return the user's input including the newline character. Therefore the input will not match `'y'` or `'n'`. To remove the tailing newline call [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) right after `gets`:

```
puts "Want a parking decal? [y/n]:"
parking = gets.chomp
```

Btw. `else parking == 'n'` does not do what you expect. It is `elsif parking == 'n'` or just `else`.